# How to import Excel to Google Sheets via web app

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a web app that will import excel file and pass it to google sheets. The idea is that different people will be uploading theirs table (format is the same) through web app to my spreadsheet where I will do the rest of the job.

For now I got this:

js code;

```
    function doGet(e) {
 
  Logger.log(e.parameter);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
     
}

function toroku(userInfo){

 var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gCMXhBTba-8PNeN5lk5wrumUGe_f4xNdip1DPCpaRSw/edit#gid=0";
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("upload");
 
  ws.appendRow([userInfo.table]);
        
 }
```

And html;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
<script>
    var ExcelToJSON = function() {

      this.parseExcel = function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
          var data = e.target.result;
          var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
            type: 'binary'
          });
          workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
            // Here is your object
            var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
            var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
            console.log(JSON.parse(json_object));
            jQuery( '#xlx_json' ).val( json_object );
          })
        };

        reader.onerror = function(ex) {
          console.log(ex);
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
      };
  };

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var xl2json = new ExcelToJSON();
    xl2json.parseExcel(files[0]);
  }


 
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="upload" type=file  name="files[]">
</form>

    <textarea class="form-control" rows=35 cols=120 id="xlx_json"></textarea>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
        document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('click', handleFileSelect).value
        
        google.script.run.toroku(handleFileSelect);
        document.getElementById("upload").value = "";

    </script>
    
    <div class="form-row">
    <button id="btn">登録！</button>
    </div>
   
    <script>
   
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",doStuff);
   
    function doStuff(){
   
    var userInfo = {};
   
   
    userInfo.table = document.getElementById("xlx_json").value;

    
     google.script.run.toroku(userInfo);
    document.getElementById("xlx_json").value = "";

   
    }
   
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

It reads the data from the excel and imports it to google sheets, but I'm getting an array not a table.

This is what I am getting imported to google sheets:

```
[{"Product":"2132030501430 ","Customer":"A","Units":"1","Deliver":"1"},{"Product":"2188130546030 ","Customer":"B","Units":"2","Deliver":"3"},{"Product":"2132650259800 ","Customer":"A","Units":"1","Deliver":"5"},{"Product":"2138512138000 ","Customer":"B","Units":"0","Deliver":"6"},{"Product":"2132032500270 ","Customer":"A","Units":"-10","Deliver":"7"},{"Product":"2116104013159 ","Customer":"B","Units":"200","Deliver":"8"},{"Product":"2116102039910 ","Customer":"A","Deliver":"9"},{"Product":"2145710030310 ","Customer":"B","Deliver":"10"},{"Product":"2132630164760 ","Customer":"A","Deliver":"9"},{"Product":"2116105051990 ","Customer":"B","Units":"0","Deliver":"5"},{"Product":"2145721006510 ","Customer":"A","Units":"0","Deliver":"4"},{"Product":"2132030900430 ","Customer":"B","Units":"7","Deliver":"3"},{"Product":"2132031500270 ","Customer":"A","Units":"5","Deliver":"2"},{"Product":"2138506049100 ","Customer":"B","Units":"6","Deliver":"1"},{"Product":"2132042501730 ","Customer":"C","Units":"31","Deliver":"9"},{"Product":"2132030901470 ","Customer":"D","Units":"20","Deliver":"8"},{"Product":"2116101050089 ","Customer":"F","Units":"126","Deliver":"7"},{"Product":"2116104051870 ","Customer":"C","Units":"3","Deliver":"6"},{"Product":"2188131528030 ","Customer":"D","Units":"82","Deliver":"4"},{"Product":"2145718013050 ","Customer":"F","Deliver":"4"},{"Product":"2188140578030 ","Customer":"C","Units":"20","Deliver":"4"},{"Product":"2132640087170 ","Customer":"D","Deliver":"4"},{"Product":"2138506026000 ","Customer":"F","Units":"0","Deliver":"4"},{"Product":"2132042501770 ","Customer":"C","Units":"15","Deliver":"4"},{"Product":"2187106025940 ","Customer":"D","Units":"90","Deliver":"4"}]
```

My question is how can I convert it into a table?
should it be done on html side?
Also I would like to say that I am newbie in programing world so please tell me in the simplest way what should I do with this.

Best Regards!

Comment: I think that the reason of your issue is to put the values to the Spreadsheet using `appendRow` as the string value of JSON object. But, I have a question of your goal. In your script, when there are multiple sheets in the XLSX, what result do you need? Because for example, when XLSX data has 2 sheets, your script send the values of only 2nd sheet to Google Apps Script side. So I cannot understand about your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of it? If you supposes that XLSX data has only one sheet or you need the last sheet of XLSX, your script can be used. How about this?

Comment: Excel file has only one sheet with one simple table
The goal is that people will be uploading this file and the app will send the data to my spreadsheet where I can do my  work

if not appendRow then what should I use?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When a XLSX file on the local PC is selected, you want to retrieve the XLSX data and put to `textarea` using Javascript and `xlsx.js`.
- When a bottom button is clicked, you want to send the values in `textarea` to Google Apps Script side, and want to put the values to the Google Spreadsheet.
- From `Excel file has only one sheet with one simple table`, I understood that the XLSX data has only one sheet.

### Modification points:

- In your script, when there are multiple sheets in the XLSX data, the values of only the last sheet are sent to Google Apps Script. Because the values of other sheets are overwritten in `workbook.SheetNames.forEach()`.

  - But from your replying, I could understand that you suppose that the XLSX data has only one sheet. So in this case, your script becomes more simple.
- In your script, an error occurs at `document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('click', handleFileSelect).value`.
- In order to put the values to the Spreadsheet, I would like to propose to use `setValues` instead of `appendRow`. When `setValues` is used, the values of the multiple rows and columns can be put with one call.

  - In this case, the values are required to be 2 dimensional array.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### Google Apps Script side:

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(e.parameter);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
}

function toroku(userInfo){
  var values = JSON.parse(userInfo.table);
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gCMXhBTba-8PNeN5lk5wrumUGe_f4xNdip1DPCpaRSw/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("upload");
  ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### HTML & Javascript side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="upload" type=file name="files[]">
  </form>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows=35 cols=120 id="xlx_json"></textarea>
  <div class="form-row">
    <button id="btn">登録！</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);
  
    var ExcelToJSON = function() {
      this.parseExcel = function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          var data = e.target.result;
          var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
          jQuery('#xlx_json').val(JSON.stringify(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]], {header: 1})));
        };
        reader.onerror = function(ex) {
          console.log(ex);
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
      };
    };

    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
      var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
      var xl2json = new ExcelToJSON();
      xl2json.parseExcel(files[0]);
    }

    function doStuff() {
      var userInfo = {};
      userInfo.table = document.getElementById("xlx_json").value;
      google.script.run.toroku(userInfo);
      document.getElementById("xlx_json").value = "";
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

### References:

- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: It works perfect! Thanks a lot!

Can you just tell me if there is any way to skip the headers of the table?

Comment: @Pimo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, when you want to remove the 1st row of the data, for example, at Google Apps Script side, how about putting `values.shift();` after the line of `var values = JSON.parse(userInfo.table);`?

Comment: values.shift() does the job!
Once again thank you very much!

Comment: @Pimo Welcome. I'm glad your additional question was resolved.

Comment: まじで助かりました！
にほんじんですかね？　僕はヨーロッパ人ですが、日本に住んでいます！
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: @Pimo ご返事ありがとうございます。日本人で、日本に住んでいます。無事解決したとのことで安心しました。こちらこそ有難うございました。