# Get original formulas from MS Excel file when converting to Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have MS Excel files with cells that use values from other MS Excel files. For instance:

MS Excel File 1: P1.xlsx ***(Cell formula B2: =[P2.xlsx]H1!$B$1)***

[image]

MS Excel File 2: P2.xlsx

[image]

So when I convert the P1.xlsx file I see the following:

[image]

My problem is how to identify the original name of the file. This is a basic example, since in the real scenario I have many cells with this behavior.

I tried with a CSV File and Google Script ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64328657/how-to-import-excel-to-google-sheets-via-web-app)) but I can't keep the file name related to that cell. So I wanted to know if there is any way to get only the formula, without modification.

Comment: You may try converting the cells with the formulas to a pure text format prior to importing them if you can easily identify which cells will have this problem.

Comment: It looks there's no other way to get the formula without modification aside from the 1st comment. However, a feature request was submitted at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174231588 & it's about "Editing or extracting information from Excel files stored in Google Drive using Google Apps Script (i.e. submitted by forms, etc.) without the need to convert these to a Google Sheet extension." I think this would be ideal for your goal as you can get raw data from the MS excel file using the Apps Script without any changes made to the file. The feature has already been submitted internally.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. When I copy the content to another Excel, I can't just copy formulas. I always have to do the change manually, right?